# Combine columnrange & stackedcolumn in Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I want to implement a similar chart to the uploaded photo. Technically, it combines 2 different stackedcolumn & columnrange into 1 chart. The 1st column is the stackedcolumn, 2nd & 3rd columns are columnrange, and the last one is a normal column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use two series and link them using the `series.linkedTo` property:

```js
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  data: [149, null, null, 187]
}, {
  linkedTo: ':previous',
  type: 'columnrange',
  data: [
    [null, null],
    [149, 175],
    [175, 187],
    [null, null]
  ]
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3rj2d7qf/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo